# Convert iptable rules to firewalld

Tags: linux, rhel, iptables, firewalld

Need your help to convert this to a firewalld command. I'm not sure that i will do it in proper way, so yeah :)

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 6110 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 6111 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8401 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8411 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Answer (score 2):

This can't be directly converted, you have to understand how both this and firewalld works.

Most of the early and late rules here are defaults for firewalld, so presumably all you want to do is open up ports.

The first one (22) is ssh, and is typically in firewalld open by default, but if it wasn't, you could add it with

```
firewall-cmd --zone public --add-service ssh --permanent
```

I don't think the remaining ones have a predefined service, so you could either create a service for them and add it as above, or you could add the port directly with

```
firewall-cmd --zone public --add-port=6110/tcp --permanent
```

The public zone is the default zone, so if you wanted to restrict a port or service to a specific subnet, you could assign the subnet to a zone (for example, work or home) and then add the port or service to that zone.

Note that you need to either rerun the firewall-cmd again without `--permanent` to make it live, or use `firewall-cmd --reload` to apply the permanent changes.

You may also want to examine `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones` to make sure there are not other (default) services open that you don't expect.  Focus on active zones and the public zone.